# How to include html page in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I want to include HTML page as a content for ion-content. I need to have multiple views of the single page.

home.ts:

```
goto(item){
    console.log(item);
  }
```

home.html:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item (click)="goto('android')">Android</ion-item>
    <ion-item (click)="goto('java')">Java</ion-item>
    <ion-item (click)="goto('ionic')">Ionic</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here, I am having different .html files for each item like android.html, ionic.html.
Once selecting the item I need to show the HTML content inside the ion-view.

Comment: Have you started an ionic project? If you have started, a generated HTML page should be in the src folder

Comment: Can you share some of your page's `code`?

Comment: I have added my .ts and html file @Sampath

Answer (score 0):

Since you have all the pages then you just need to do this: You can use `navCtrl.push()` as shown below.

*home.ts*

```
goto(item:string){

    switch(item) {
    case "android":
        this.navCtrl.push(AndroidPage);
        break;
    case "java":
         this.navCtrl.push(JavaPage);
        break;
    case "ionic":
         this.navCtrl.push(IonicPage);
        break;
    default:
    }
 }
```

You can learn [**basics of Ionic here**](https://www.joshmorony.com/beginners-guide-to-getting-started-with-ionic-2/).

Comment: Thanks, @Sampath.  Here  Android, Java are the home page items. Once selected the item (Android or Java) . need to go to detailsPage
this.navCtrl.push(DetailsPage);  Inside the details page I need to display the content from my .html files(Android.html or Java.html) as part of the details.html

Comment: can you show the one of your `Android.html` file's code?